# Creating5 icons when installing the apk in the device

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

In my app I have create 4 option menu using

```java
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

Now when I am installing the apk on the device, it shows 5 icon of the apk in the device. 4 of the icons will direct it in to the particular menu click, while one icon will direct to the app.
why it is happening?

Comment: 5 icons are showing on option menu? or in all application in device

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about how you call that? I.e., give some of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have used the following code in every activity tag in maifest file

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

use this intent filter only in launcher activity